# How to change MediaPlayer volume in different activity

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have a `MediaPlayer` in my app which starts playing on the main menu, and activity which is always open. It is created using the following code:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.relaxedmusic);
    mp.start();
    mp.setVolume(1, 1);
    mp.setLooping(true);
```

The `MediaPlayer`, "mp", keeps playing as new activities are opened and closed, and is muted with the following code:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (musicThroughActivity == 1) {
        mp.setVolume(1, 1);
    } else if (musicThroughActivity == 0) {
        mp.setVolume(0, 0);
    }

}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (musicThroughActivity == 1) {
        mp.setVolume(1, 1);
    } else if (musicThroughActivity == 0) {
        mp.setVolume(0, 0);
    }

}
```

However, if the user exits the app from another activity (e.g., hits the home button whilts Item 1's activity is opened), the music keeps playing. Is there any way to change the volume of a MediaPlayer from an activity different to where it was created?

All help appreciated.

Comment: add a static reference of your MediaPlayer in your Activity or use a singleton class

Comment: How do I do add a static reference? EDIT: I'm googling it and nothing's coming up.

Comment: look my answer @Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a static reference of your MediaPlayer in your Activity or use a singleton class

if you want to add a static reference,  find in your code the line

```
 MediaPlayer mp;
```

and change it for:

```
public static MediaPlayer mp;
```

then from any activity you can call

```
 MainActivity.mp.setVolume(1, 1);
```